# Making it loop back to the beginning

Tags: c++, loops

I am pretty new to the coding world so my coding isn't that great. I am doing a project and trying to make it loop back to the beginning after the calculations.
I'm not 100% on what I'm doing so I do apologize ahead of time. If I run it like this it gives me the error of having a "else" without a previous "if". I had it in a do loop but a friend told me I could just do it like this. Thank you in advance for you tips/advice.[The code][1] Sorry I don't know how to post the code in this block.Edit, Not sure what to add as my while statement at the end to make it loop back.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

   int main () {
    char C = 'C';
    char c = 'c';
    char x = 'x';
    char X = 'X';
    char s ='s';
    char S ='S';
    char r = 'r';
    char R = 'R';
    char t = 't';
    char T = 'T';
do{
    char C = 'C';
    char c = 'c';
    char x = 'x';
    char X = 'X';
    char s ='s';
    char S ='S';
    char r = 'r';
    char R = 'R';
    char t = 't';
    char T = 'T';
    cout<<"Please enter C for circle , S for square , R for rectangle , T for triangle(right) , X to exit"<<endl;
    cin >> x;
    if ((x==C)||(x==c)){
            cout<<"Please enter radius"<<endl;
            float c1;
            float c2;
            cin>>c1;
            c2=c1*2*3.14;
            cout<<"The Area= "<<c2<<endl;
            }else if ((x==s)||(x==S)) {
                    cout<<"Please enter side"<<endl;
                    float s1;
                    cin>>s1;
                    float s2;
                    s2=s1*2;
                    cout<<"The radius= "<<s2<<endl;
                    }else if ((x==t)||(x==T)) {
                            cout<<"Please enter leg"<<endl;
                            float t1;
                            cin>>t1;
                            cout<<"Please enter leg 2"<<endl;
                            float t3;
                            cin>>t3;
                            float t2;
                            t2=(t3*t1)/2;
                            cout<<"The radius= "<<t2<<endl;
                            }else if ((x==r)||(x==R)){
                                    cout<<"Please enter Width"<<endl;
                                    float w1;
                                    cin>>w1;
                                    cout<<"Please enter Length"<<endl;
                                    float w2;
                                    cin>>w2;
                                    float w3;
                                    w3=w1*w2;
                                    }else ((x==X)||(x==x));{
                                            break;
                                    }
                              }while ((x=!c)||(x=!C)||(x!=s)||(x!=S)||(x!=t)||(x!=T)||(x!=x)||(x!=X)||(x!=r)||(x!=R));
                      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code included into your question please, not as a link or image. Make sure its a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Sorry I changed it.

Comment: Off topic: You can save yourself the trouble of testing for both upper  and lower case letters by converting the input to always be upper or lower case. For example: `if (tolower(x) == 'c')`. Also look into the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your first `else` statement, you inserted a semicolon accidentally.

```
else ((x==5)||(x==5));
```

Remove the semicolon and you should be fine!

Also it should be `else if` instead of `else`. Basically, the format goes like `if`, `else if`, `else`.

```
variable=true
if(variable==true) 
{
. // do something
} 

else if(variable==false) 
{
 //do something else
} 
else
{
 // do something else
}
```

An `else` statement doesn't have a condition.  It's for when it doesn't match all of these, do this! If you still don't understand, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm) should give you a good understanding of `if`, `else if`, `else` statements

Again, if you are struggling, please take a read here.  It explains it well:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm

Comment: Thank you for that , sorry to ask so much , I have to add a while statement at the end to make it loop back through. I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Or do I even need to use a "do" loop?

Comment: Is there a limit to the amount of "else" statements you can have?

Comment: @HieuNguyen you clearly don't understand the if/elseif/else concept if you ask that question.  Have you read the link I gave you?  The should explain you very well.  And yes you can only have one else statement for each if statements.

Comment: @amanuel2 If you hadn't commented on that link I wouldn't have known it existed. I had to go back and reread your post to find it. I recommend using more than one word as a hypertext link to make it stand out better.

Comment: @user4581301 done.  I have to sleep now. Commented right before I was about to sleep :P

Comment: Thanks Upvoted. Have a great sleep, and then wake up refreshed and wonder how you can have a third option  with `true` and `false`.

Comment: I re did it but it gives me a declaration before "}" error on line 72. Thank you all for the comments i'm slowly getting it done!

Comment: @HieuNguyen its probably because you are missing the code.. You mind posting your updated code?

Comment: @user4581301 you can't lol.  This is just an example.  But it is impossible to have another option other than true and false

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want this to infinitely repeat for the user, and you're trying to use a do-while loop.

```
do {

// Whatever you're doing

} while (condition);
```

Usually you can create some type of bool and set it to true when you want to exit the loop, so you can do:

```
bool getMeOut = false;

do {
    // Some Stuff

    if (condition for exit)
        getMeOut = true;

} while (getMeOut == false);
```

And you'll be stuck in that loop until you set getMeOut to true!

Best of luck!

Comment: I re did it but it gives me a declaration before "}" error on line 72

Comment: @HieuNguyen I can't really see your code so I'm not too sure what's happening on line 72. Just go over your code and make sure you did all the basics correctly!